# data.table subsetting in i with column number

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to subset a data.table in `i`, referencing the column not by its name (e.g. by number/position)?

Example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A=1:18, Name=c('A','B','C'))
dt2 <- data.table(A=2:20, Username=c('A','B','C'))

#stuff happens and eventually I end up with either dt or dt2 copied to a final dt

#depending on which is there, I want to get only "A"s
final[Name=='A']
final[Username=='A']
```

But I want a way that I can subset both data.tables with the same call despite the different column names. One potential solution is to set the key for each dt as `Name` and `Username`, then subset like this: `final['A']` but I am wondering if there is another way.

I can't change the column names because they are going into a table in a shiny app.

Comment: what is `final`?

Comment: It is a copy of either `dt` or `dt2`

Comment: Ah smart, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is based on position, then we extract the column with numeric column index using `[[` and do the comparison to get the logical vector and subset the rows based on it

```
final[final[[2]]=="A"]
```